# Spring Data Hadoop and Hbase 1+

Tags: hbase, spring-data-hadoop

Since recently, hbase released the [hbase 1.2,](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel) and there is a huge number of bugs fixed in [hbase 1.0.0+](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/start_of_a_new_era), I am wondering if Spring is going to upgrade to use the new API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Not Yet](https://twitter.com/trisberg/status/643886033281642496). But, probably in near [future](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SHDP-524).